# Stuck at Laravel , trying to save datas in database

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing this function to call it later, but what is saving in database are only `first_name`, `password` and `email`. There is `null` for `user_create_id` and `user_update_id`.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'user_create_id'=> '0',
        'user_update_id'=> '0',  ]);
}
```

Is there any way to save  `user_create_id` and `user_update_id`?

Comment: Check you fillables property inside your model. You must have `user_create_id` and `user_update_id` in there.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your user model, you probably need to update the fillable property to include those attributes, something like:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname',
    'password',
    'email',
    'user_create_id',
    'user_update_id'
];
```

Unless you've set a guarded property instead, in which case you'd just want to ensure that none of those attributes are in the guarded property as it acts as a black list where fillable acts as a while list for mass attribute assignment.  A workable guarded version would look like this

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
protected $fillable = [
    ....
    'user_create_id'=> '0',
    'user_update_id',
];
```

Inside `User` class

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

> You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. However, before doing so, *you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model*, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

Make sure `user_create_id` and `user_update_id` are in your `app/User.php` file's `$fillable` definition.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these properties are fillable. Also make sure that the column type supports strings, as you're using `'0'` which is a string, not an integer:

Fillable:

```
// User model

protected $fillable = [
    'first_name',
    'password',
    'email',
    'user_create_id',
    'user_update_id'
];
```